# Trying to modify the background of a form on a specific page

Tags: css, plugin-gravity-forms

Here's my CSS:

```
.page-id-9399 body #gform_wrapper_3 {
    background-color: #363c42;
}
```

This is related to a Gravity Forms (contact form submission).

I'd like the background of the FORM to be the color as above.

I thought the above code would work because the Page ID os 9399

I think it is the reference "body" that throws this CSS snippet.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of phrasing it is to just MOVE the body. The page-id class is applied to the body, so:

```
body.page-id-9399 #gform_wrapper_3 {
    background-color: #363c42;
}
```

Would have worked